# ¿Qué tiene el paquete de Meteor accounts-base que no tenga en accounts-password?

Tags: meteor, cuenta-usuario

Estaba viendo un *screencast* sobre el sistema de cuentas de usuario de [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) y el autor del video usaba el paquete [accounts-base](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-base), además de accounts-password, accounts-ui y accounts-twiter.

Conocía esos paquetes, excepto por [accounts-base](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-base). Entiendo que **accounts-ui** es lo que te da la ventana de login, si no quieres construir tus propias pantallas de login. **Accounts-password** te deja crear cuentas de usuario y puedes parametrizar los datos que serán necesarios para el login con algo del estilo:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  //passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
});
```

y accounts-twitter (o accounts-google, etc. ) para configurar el acceso mediante una cuenta de twitter, google, weibo, github...

Veo que account-ui, accounts-password, y en general accounts-XYZ dependen de este paquete, pero no me queda claro qué funcionalidad tiene este paquete de por sí. Es decir, no sé qué justificaría hacer un `meteor add accounts-base` sin querer añadir accounts-password. No sé si es que obtengo toda su funcionalidad por defecto al hacer un `meteor add accounts-password`, por ejemplo.

¿Tiene el paquete **accounts-base** algo que no venga ya en los otros paquetes de cuentas de usuario en Meteor?

Nota: el video es bastante antiguo, y en algunos momentos usa cosas como `Meteor.autosubscribe`, que sé que ha sido ya deprecado en favor de `Deps.autorun` o `Tracker.autorun`. No sé si en algún momento era necesario añadir este paquete básico  y luego su funcionalidad se incorporó en otros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la respuesta a esta pregunta buscando información relacionada con el mecanismo de `login` y `logout` en `Meteor`.

> The basic Accounts system is in the accounts-base package, but applications typically include this automatically by adding one of the login provider packages: accounts-password, accounts-facebook, accounts-github, accounts-google, accounts-meetup, accounts-twitter, or accounts-weibo
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Meteor accounts API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api)</sub>

Que básicamente viene a decir

> La funcionalidad básica para el sistema de Cuentas se encuentra en el paquete **accounts-base**, pero otras aplicaciones típicamente incluyen esta funcionalidad de manera automática al incluir uno de los siguientes paquetes para proveedores de login: ***accounts-password**, accounts-facebook, accounts-github, accounts-google, accounts-meetup, accounts-twitter, or accounts-weibo.*
>
> (traducción mía)

Así que realmente no hay nada en `accounts-base` que no se encuentre en `accounts-password`. El uso del paquete `accounts-password` por sí mismo te "libera" de tener que agregar también `accounts-base`. Idem con los otros paquetes que proporcionan login en base a una cuenta en un proveedor con `Facebook`, `Google`, etc.